# How to disable caching in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer, cache, internet-explorer-9, browser-cache

How can i disable caching in Internet Explorer 9?

i browse to a page, and click a link.  When i click **Back**, i **need** the browser to always re-fetch the page from the web-site.

---

i've tried disabling the browser cache by going into:

- Tools
- Internet Options
- Under **Browsing History**, click **Settings**
- Under **Check for newer versions of stored pages**, select **Every time I visit the webpage**

  [image]

Except that doesn't cause Internet Explorer 9 (32-bit (Windows 7 (64-bit( Professional)))) to reload the page when clicking the **Back** button.

How do i disable caching in Internet Explorer 9?

---

i use **Fiddler** to watch if Internet Explorer 9 makes an HTTP request to the server when i click the **Back** button:

[image]

And Internet Explorer 9 does **not** request the page from the server; instead serving it from the cache.

How do i disable caching in Internet Explorer 9?

---

i've tried changing the **Browser Mode** (the version of Internet Explorer that Internet Explorer 9 reports to the server) to **IE8*, as well as changing the **Document Mode** (the version of Internet Explorer rendering engine that Internet Explorer 9 uses to render the page), and in both cases the browser does not request the page when clicking back.

How do i disable caching in Internet Explorer 9?

---

**Update**: i tried reducing the maximum cache size in Internet Explorer 9 to the lowest allowable value: **8 MB**:

[image]

and restarting my browser, but Internet Explorer 9 does not re-fetch the page from the cache when i click **Back**:

[image]

instead showing the old, cached, version of the web-page.

How do i disable caching in Internet Explorer 9?

Comment: IE's probably caching the data in memory not disk. If that can't be controlled, you might want to consider using another browser where it can be like Firefox and adjusting its cache settings using information described [here](http://www.speedguide.net/articles/firefox-ie-browser-tweaks-2448) but with different values so that caching of both kinds is suppressed.

Comment: @martineau HTTP1.1 ([RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) ) dictates that browsers "**SHOULD NOT**" *(emphasis not added)* refresh a page when the user click's **Back** (or Forward). IE **is** (as is Firefox and Chrome) caching the data. It cannot be disabled through any IE program option (or Chrome option, but we cannot switch to any other browser - so it's a moot point).

Comment: So what's going to happen, the W3C police coming and arresting you for refreshing a page? Very doubtful. Can't switch browsers? Hogwash, millions have, including my 80 year old mother. An easier alternative for yours might be to have her use `Ctrl+F5`, one of the [47 Keyboard Shortcuts That Work in All Web Browsers](http://www.howtogeek.com/114518/47-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-in-all-web-browsers) to get a fresh copy of the web page being viewed. It's also possible in Firefox to install an add-on that will provide a toolbar icon that can be pressed to clear the cache on demand.

Comment: @martineau i *could* switch to another browser but it doesn't change the behavior - all browsers follow the RFC (test it). She **can** press `F5`, that's not the problem - the problem is that she **has** to press `F5`. Google, Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, they've all solved by problem by adding `no-cache, no-store`. And i've been unable to convince the author of [my mother's favorite site to do the same](http://www.ravelry.com/discuss/for-the-love-of-ravelry/2252084). So i'm left with a client-side permanent solution.

Comment: I was wondering by you **needed** the browser to do this. Again, if a different browser were used, such as Firefox or Chrome, you could use the [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/stylish) browser extension to effectively modify the site without the need to convince its authors to change it for you. On the other hand, I'm sure your mum is capable of learning to press `Ctrl+F5` (or hold down the `Shift` key while pressing the Back-Arrow button or key, which while not universal, also do the job in Firefox) when using this one website.

Comment: Here's some [general information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish) about Stylish.

Comment: no easy way, hit ctrl+F5 after you use the back button

Comment: @martineau She knows about pressing `F5` after clicking `Back` to refresh the page. She reported the problem that the page doesn't refresh *unless* she presses `F5`.

Comment: @IanBoyd: One could argue that not reloading a web page is the correct behavior of the Back button -- it's to take you back to what you were just viewing -- if you want to reload it to pick up any changes you have to do something extra. I'm just trying to suggest ways to get the browsing behavior you say you **need**.

Comment: @martineau Not reloading a web-page **is** the correct behavior of the Back button in a browser (RFC2616). The behavior that i (i.e. my mother) **needs** is to reload a web-page when the Back button is pressed. Finding a way to completely disable the cache is my attempt to solve that. If the cache in IE9 cannot be disabled, then that is the answer. There's no shame in saying "You cannot do that".

Comment: @Ian Boyd: I'm not attempting to save face, only just suggesting some alternative ways to obtain the browsing experience/behavior you seek. If you're fixated on IE9 and willing to settle for "IE9 can't do that", that's fine with me. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To do this, simply press <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up the Developer view, click the **Cache** menu, and select **Always refresh from server**. The next time you load a page in that tab, it will redownload everything every time you navigate.

This setting will not carry over to other tabs or be retained when you close the browser, however.

Comment: My mother will not be able to accomplish that once; let alone every time she browses :(

Comment: Yay, now I can debug my .js files once again ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Can you force ie9 to use a local CSS that has the following in it:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</HEAD><BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In IE9, to use a local style sheet, simply click on the gear menu on the top right, and then click on **Internet Options**. Under the General tab, click the **Accessibility** button, and then check the checkbox labeled **Format documents using my style sheet**. Then browse to a text file with the code above.

Here's a screenshot of the option you want:
[image]

Comment: i don't control the HTML of the web-sites my mother is browsing. :(

Comment: @IanBoyd Local Style Sheets can be appended to any site you browse by the browser. You don't need access to the websites' code itself.

Comment: @sidran32 Thanks for finding this, my IE isn't NEARLY as strong as my Safari... I really appreciate you pointing it out.  +1

Comment: This doesn't work for the *going back* cache policy (i just tested it). If i click **Back** Internet Explorer doesn't issue another http request.

Comment: All right, I tried.  I was looking for ANYTHING that would help.  Thanks for letting me know.  I'll leave this posted so that people know this isn't an answer.

Comment: If I were the programmer for IE9, I would set it up so delete (going back) doesn't use a cache policy (on the HD), but uses a section of memory (it's faster).  I think you're spinning your wheels.  Are you SURE that IE9 actually makes a call to the cache when you use back?

Comment: @Everett Yes, i am sure. Look at Fidder screenshot above - i'm *absolutely sure*. You can test it for yourself if you like: it's repeatable in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: @IanBoyd - If I understand the Fiddler screen shots correctly, they are showing that IE9 is not making a request for the page you were at when you "go back."  That means the information exists on the computer somewhere, we agree on this.  I also understand the cache exists on the Hard drive.  What I'm asking is, are you sure that when you hit back that IE9 makes a call to the cache on the hard drive and not a section of memory.  I don't see where Fiddler proves that.

Comment: @Everett Oh, i can't guaratee that the file isn't served from memory, memory that has been swapped to the pagefile, or a cache database - no. But i am sure that IE makes a call to the cache (whether it be in ram, in memory, in virtual memory, in the swap file, in a cache file)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: No, you cannot disable the cache in Internet Explorer 9.

- you can limit the cache size
- you can ask IE to refresh the page every time you navigate to it
- you can press F5 to manually reload a page

But you can still be served cached versions of a page (i.e. a version that is not up-to-date with the state of the server).